# Image hover moves text?

Tags: css, text

I can't figure out how to keep some text stagnant inside a container whilst an image is transformed/transitions into a larger size. I have tried using position and z-index but to no avail. Any tips or advice?

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/j2qx9d8g/142/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@800&display=swap');

body {
  background-color: #4169e1;
}

.cards {
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.card-body {
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 330px;
  height: 310px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: -8px 8px 13px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-body:hover {
  box-shadow: -2px 14px 9px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-img {
  z-index: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card-img:hover {
  height: 100%;
}

.card__info {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.card__category {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #868686;
}

.card__title {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.card__by {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.card__author {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #AD7D52;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595306049322-197897add10b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80">
    <div class="card-category">
      <span class="card__category">LIFE + SELF-HELP</span>
      <h3 class="card__title">Why You Probably Are Going to Fail Your Resolutions</h3>
      <span class="card__by">by <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">John Doe</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578031896083-555b2beab127?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=967&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508009603885-50cf7c579365?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=947&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515003233195-4a6c9dc5cbf9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505471768190-275e2ad7b3f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=800">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509682841784-c7960cbb7608?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1006&q=80">
  </div>
</div>
```

p.s. if any one could give any advice on how to center the text in the middle of the white section that would also be appreciated. Trying padding/margins has not worked for me (at least in the section of css class .card_info) but I may just not be doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So I added cointerner that cointein img, and make its parent to display grid. I hope this is what you mean.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@800&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: #4169e1;
    display: flex;
}

.cards {
    margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.card-body {
    z-index: -3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 310px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: -8px 8px 13px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-body:hover {
    box-shadow: -2px 14px 9px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-img {
    z-index: 2;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.myimage:hover > .card-img{
    width: 120%;
    left: -10%;
}

.card-category{
    z-index: 4;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.card__info {
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.card__category {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #868686;
}

.card__title {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.card__by {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.card__author {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AD7D52;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="myimage">
            <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595306049322-197897add10b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="card-category">
            <span class="card__category">LIFE + SELF-HELP</span>
            <h3 class="card__title">Why You Probably Are Going to Fail Your Resolutions</h3>
            <span class="card__by">by <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">John Doe</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="myimage">
            <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595306049322-197897add10b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="card-category">
            <span class="card__category">LIFE + SELF-HELP</span>
            <h3 class="card__title">Why You Probably Are Going to Fail Your Resolutions</h3>
            <span class="card__by">by <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">John Doe</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="myimage">
            <img class="card-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595306049322-197897add10b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80">
        </div>
        <div class="card-category">
            <span class="card__category">LIFE + SELF-HELP</span>
            <h3 class="card__title">Why You Probably Are Going to Fail Your Resolutions</h3>
            <span class="card__by">by <a href="#" class="card__author" title="author">John Doe</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This may work but what I was really looking for was for the text to stay and the image to fill the background. The white space would disappear and what would be left would be the image and the background. I'll fiddle with the code a bit more but any advice or help would be much appreciated!